# re-using the com.google.gson.Gson object in a service or servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, gson

I have a rest web service:

```
@Path("/tranreq")
public class TranscriptRequesterResource {
    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getTranscriptRequests() {
        // use GSON here
    }
}
```

Is this safe to make the Gson object a static final constant and re-use it for everyone of the multi-threaded requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used GSON in this way in the past with no issues. One instance seems plenty.

Comment: I've been using it as a static shared variable amongst many threads now for a while... and no problems. Seems good. So I marked your answer correct.